# Java: What is the different between AtomicBoolean and a static boolean variable when locking a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, boolean

I write a thread class called T.

My purpose is to make sure only one thread object running at a time.

So when the thread object is called, it would check a boolean flag called BUSY.

My question is what is the different between

```
private static AtomicBoolean BUSY = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

and

```
private static boolean BUSY = false;
```

I thought if using the 'static', all object would only check one BUSY boolean variable so that would make sure only one thread object is running.

Answer (score 8):

You must at least make the boolean variable `volatile` and the AtomicBoolean variable `final` in order to have a comparable solution. After you do that, there will be no difference for your use case.

The difference comes about if you use `AtomicBoolean`'s `getAndSet` or `compareAndSet` methods, which combine one read and one write action into an atomic whole, whereas these are not atomic when done against a `volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `boolean` and with proper synchronization (and making `volatile`) can achieve what you need.
But by using the `AtomicBoolean` you can check the current value atomically without the need to write code for synchronization yourself

Answer (score 0):

As said by others you must make the variables final / volatile respectively.

From what you describe I fear you have a place where you do something like this:

```
if (!BUSY){
    BUSY = true;
}
```

Note that this is broken in absence of commons synchronization, because two threads might check the flag, both seeing it as false and starting their work.

I suggest looking into the existing structures for handling concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Especially [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with a single permit might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A useful feature of an `AtomicBoolean` is to allow a single thread to continue if and only if BUSY is false but not to let any other threads to continue.

```
private static AtomicBoolean BUSY = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public void doWork(){
  if(BUSY.compareAndSet(false,true)){
     //do some work
     BUSY.set(false);
  }else{
     //some other thread won, return now or retry later?
  }
}
```

So here only one thread will `doWork` at any given time.  You cannot achieve this with a `volatile boolean` because you cannot be sure that `Thread.currentThread()` set the boolean.

Comment: I suggest to perform the `BUSY.set(false)` in a `finally` to be sure it actually gets done.